# OAuth 2.0/OpenID Connect: Get notification when user deleted from Identity provider

Tags: java, oauth, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, spring-oauth2

Does OAuth2 and/or OpenID Connect have a feature to notify the client (e.g my app) about user deletions? If so is it part of the standard, or just some providers have it, some don’t?

Let’s have an example:

1. User registers in my app with his Github account (or any oauth2 id. Provider)
2. Starts working, do changes and saves stuff
3. Decides to delete his account from github.

Does oauth2 have a mechanism for this scenario to somehow let my application know that ‘hey, this user deleted himself, clean up after him’?

Another example could be this site. I registered with my Github account. How would StackOverflow know it needs to delete my comments once my github account is long gone?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There's no standard mechanism in the "OAuth canon" (collection of OAuth specs including OpenID Connect) to address this *yet*. The closest is the Security Events (secevents). The [push-based delivery](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secevent-http-push-14) of a [Security Event Token (SET)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8417.html) is still a draft. The RISC working group at the OpenID Foundation is working to define SETs for [token issued, token revoked](https://openid.net/specs/oauth-event-types-1_0-ID1.html), [account disabled, account purged](https://openid.net/specs/openid-risc-event-types-1_0-ID1.html), etc. events.

So, the answer to your question, currently, is no, but in time will be yes.

Comment: Thank you! In the meantime i have found a workaround using the identity server for this purpose.